# How to add # characters after the end of last character in the line till its length?

Tags: linux, shell

I am very new to the Linux world and looking to perform below.

```
The process of writing a      job description requires having a clear understanding of the job’s duties and    responsibilities.                                                         
The job posting should also include a concise picture of the skills required                                                                     
for the position to attract qualified job candidates.                                                
Organize the job description       into five sections:         Company Information, Job Description, Job Requirements,                             
Benefits and a Call to Action.        Be sure to include keywords that will help make your           job posting searchable.                                  
A well-defined job description will help attract             qualified candidates as well                                                                       
as help reduce employee turnover                   in the long run.
```

I've data in **sample.conv** file now by executing the shell script or command I want to convert to

```
The process of writing a      job description requires having a clear understanding of the job’s duties and    responsibilities. ########################################### 
The job posting should also include a concise picture of the skills required ############################################################################################################
for the position to attract qualified job candidates.######################
Organize the job description       into five sections:         Company Information, Job Description, Job Requirements,################### 
Benefits and a Call to Action.        Be sure to include keywords that will help make your           job posting searchable.######################## 
A well-defined job description will help attract             qualified candidates as well####################################### 
as help reduce employee turnover                   in the long run.############################################################
```

Note - sample.conv is not a fixed length file. In actual file contains spaces for those spaces I've shown # here which ultimately I want to achieve.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to replace trailing spaces with octothorpes?

Comment: Yes I want to remove all trailing spaces with #, only after last character of the file and not in between of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/( +)$/"#" x length $1/e' file
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, printing each line after processing
- `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` is a substitution
- `( +)` matches any number of spaces and stores the matched string in $1
- `$` matches a line end, i.e. the spaces must appear at the end of a line to match
- the `/e` modifier interprets the replacement as code
- `x` is the repetition operator, it repeats `#` as many times as was the length of the $1, i.e. how many spaces there were

Comment: How can we get output of command in a separate file ?

Comment: Or how can we update the current file or rename it ?

Comment: Use redirection to capture the output (see `man bash`), or the `-i` option to change the file in place (see [perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun)).

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -i 's/[[:space:]]+$//' file
```

Substitute one or more spaces, end of line for nothing.